# Why doesn't this JS work? (window.scrollTop)

Tags: javascript, jquery

The class 'stuck-sm' is added, but 'stuck-md' is not.

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 285) {
  $('.something').addClass('stuck-sm');
} else if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 430) {
  $('.something').addClass('stuck-md');
} else {
  $('.something').removeClass('stuck-sm','stuck-md');
}
```

Comment: `else` means "else" - `if`/`else` always only executes one block

Comment: Did you try to debug it?

Comment: Because `>=430` is also `>=285` so your first block runs, then the 2nd doesn't run as it wouldn't only run when the first doesn't due to the "else".

Answer (score 1):

else if is reachable only if the value is less than 285 which means second else if block won't get execute. Below is the correct  solution.

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 430) {
   $('.something').addClass('stuck-md');
} else if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 285) {
   $('.something').addClass('stuck-sm');
} else {
   $('.something').removeClass('stuck-sm','stuck-md');
}
```